# Does anyone know what are these pipes coming out of the ground?

Tags: pipe

Does anyone know what are these pipes coming out of the ground for? saw them at a cabin I was looking at, but see these sometimes in farms too.

[image: What are these pipes?]

Comment: Could be where the bodies are buried.

Comment: @SolarMike   LOL dude!  but they "might" be related to septic tanks/drainfields (or leach fields) depending upon what part of the country you're in .

Comment: They use those to vent gases from garbage heaps.  You never know.

Comment: They're vents.  Probably for some sort of sewage system, but you also see them around gas lines and the like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Near human habitation with "indoor plumbing?" Those are Septic tank (and associated plumbing)vents. They provide positive ventilation and also mean there's no mystery about where to dig for it when needed.

*Not a good place to hang your hammock.*

Comment: And don't light up a cigarette...